# bug when displaying selectonemenu primefaces inside p panelgrid

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, panel

I have this problem : 
[image]

here is the code :

```
    <p:panelGrid styleClass="newArticlePanelGrid" >

<!-- __________________________________________row1________________________________________________ -->
<p:row>

<p:column>
<h:outputLabel value="Designation : " />                        
</p:column>
<p:column colspan="3" >
<p:inputText id="new-article-designation"  style="width: 449px;"
                            value="#{articlesMB.article.designation}" required="true"
                            requiredMessage="designation requise" />

</p:column>

</p:row>

<p:row>

<p:column />
<p:column colspan="3" >
<p:message id="for-new-article-designation"
                            for="new-article-designation" display="text" />
</p:column>


</p:row>
<!-- __________________________________________row2________________________________________________ -->
<p:row>

<p:column>
<h:outputLabel value="Type : " />

</p:column>
<p:column>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="new-article-typeggg" required="true"
                            requiredMessage="type requis" converter="#{typeConverter}"
                            style="width:100%" value="#{articlesMB.article.type}">
                            <!--        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selectionner Type" itemValue="" />-->
                            <f:selectItems value="#{articlesMB.listTypes}" var="v"
                                itemLabel="#{v.libelle}" itemValue="#{v}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

</p:column>
<p:column>
    <h:outputLabel value="Unité : " />

</p:column>
<p:column>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="new-article-unite" required="true"
                            widgetVar="uniteselect" requiredMessage="unité requise"
                            converter="#{uniteConverter}" style="width:100%"
                            value="#{articlesMB.article.unite}">
                            <!--            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selectionner Unite" itemValue=""  /> -->
                            <f:selectItems value="#{articlesMB.listUnites}" var="v"
                                itemLabel="#{v.libelle}" itemValue="#{v}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

</p:column>

</p:row>

<p:row>

<p:column />
<p:column>
```

I don't know what I should do to reolve this problem : I tested `width:100%` but as you see it doesn't change

how can I resolve that ?

thank you in advance

Comment: You should post selectonemenu xhtml code.

Comment: I have never seen this thing before. Add more code.

Comment: sorry for delay, RongNK and Makky: I had write all codes move scrollbar and see code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem come from `style="100%"`, it only change selectonemenu's width, you should set width for label inside selectonemenu(in this situation):

```
            <style type="text/css">
                .ui-selectonemenu-label{
                    width:100% !important;
                }
            </style>
```

If you want set all selectonemenu:

```
             <style type="text/css">
                .ui-selectonemenu-label{
                    width:100% !important;
                }
                .ui-selectonemenu{
                    width:100% !important;
                }
            </style>
```

for more general, you can include in css file.

**See also:** [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used?lq=1)